# Subquery amount not coming in full

Tags: sql, sum

I have this query:

```
Select I.Invoice_Number, PA.Invoice_Number, I.Line_Amount, PA.Invoiced_Amount
from XXX as PA
Left join (select Invoice_Number, Line_Amount from Invoices) as I
on PA.Invoice_Number = I.Invoice_Number
Group by PA.Invoice_Number;
```

Both should give me the same amount of cost (I.Line_Amount = PA.Invoice_Amount) per Invoice_Number, yet I.Line_Amount is only bringing the first row on the list, while PA.Invoiced.Number brings the sum of the cost on that Invoice.

I tried using sum(Line_Amount) within the subquery but all records come out as Null.

Is there a way for me to join both tables and make sure that the amounts per invoice match to the total amount of that invoice?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (and you want to make sure that sum of `Line_Amount` in `Invoices` table is the same as `Invoiced_Amount` in `XXX` table) the second table should have invoice number and sum of amounts:

```
select I.Invoice_Number, PA.Invoice_Number, I.total, PA.Invoiced_Amount
from XXX as PA
left join (
    select Invoice_Number, sum(Line_Amount) as total
    from Invoices
    group by Invoice_Number
) as I
on PA.Invoice_Number = I.Invoice_Number
```

You can try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1d010/1/0